# Is it always neccessary to hide the mysql generated id from the user?

Tags: php, mysql, security, auto-increment

Is it a security risk to show the actual id, auto incremented by the database, to the user? Can you give some practical examples of what people can do dangerous with it?

Comment: I think it's bad style to leak internal ids into the UI. But it's not always avoidable (internal ids are often the primary ids), and it's most certainly not generally a security issue.

Comment: @mario Why is it a bad style? Because it is potentially dangerous? I'm asking because I can, technically, avoid it with a little bit of hassle if it's really important.

Comment: Nope, not dangerous per se. It's just that you shouldn't have internal numbering (which exists mainly for relational database mapping) become external numbering. It's often reasoned with SEO. But I would just say numbers are less user-friendly, and unless needed for relocatability shouldn't be exposed in URLs.

Comment: @mario My id is never exposed in an url. Just passed along in a form that you can only see if you view the source of the page. Besides, using a combination of numbers and an "url friendly" name is probably better for your sanity and is (practically) just as user-friendly and SEO compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any reason exposing the row id to the user is inherently insecure. Pretty much all web frameworks do this at some point.

Using an incrementing integer id exposes some information about the underlying data. Most importantly they are generally sequential so a potential attacker can predict ids that will likely be valid. However, if you are allowing a user to request data from your app for an id he might not have permission to see, then there are probably larger security issues with your app. If you are are properly restricting access, or access to record data doesn't need to be restricted, then exposing the id doesn't pose much (if any) risk.

Answer (score 5):

No, it is used in many contexts.

If your website is vulnerable in another way, say SQL injection or XSS, they can maybe use the id to something harmfull. But never with the id alone.

Just by looking at your profile here at SO, your id is **243414**

Answer (score 2):

It's not dangerous alone.

If your system have any exploit id can help them

But don't forget if your system vulnerable any information is dangerous just id makes it easier

Answer (score 0):

It can be tragedy sometimes

lets say I have a profile on your application and I have my pictures on that profile 
And when I delete one of them the link is like this

http://www.yourapp.com/myprofile/pictures/delete_pic.php?id=5

and this is my pic 
imagine that the pic 19 is not mine

http://www.yourapp.com/myprofile/pictures/delete_pic.php?id=19

Here i will delete another user's picture 
If you need to show such id to the user encrypt them when show and decrypt them when use 
you can use

```
base64_encode() & base64_decode()
```

but this is very simple and can be obtained you can make your own algorithm or do something for generating different output from base64 like

```
base64_encode($id+7); or loops
```

Comment: Well that's why before deleting the picture, I will check if you really are allowed to delete the picture or not.

Comment: Yes sure you should but i gave you an example what it can do if not written probably